# Ember data model setter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the most simple way to override setter for `DS.Model`. I have

```
month: DS.attr('date'),    
monthSetter: function() {
   const rawDate = this.get('month');
   if (rawDate) {
       var start = new Date(rawDate.getFullYear(), rawDate.getMonth(), 1);
       this.set('month', start);
   }
}.observes('month'),
```

and, of course, it gives an infinite loop. I need month property to be always beginning of month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed use a computed property to deal with this:

```
monthObject: Ember.computed('month', {
  get() {
    return this.get('month');
  },
  set(key, val) {
    let value = val;
    if (val) {
      value = new Date(rawDate.getFullYear(), rawDate.getMonth(), 1);
    }
    this.set('month', value);
    return val;
  }
})
```

And use `monthObject` in your template,

Comment: Well, I guess there's no other way... Btw, I guess you meant `this.get(val)` instead of `this.get('month')`. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: no `this.get('month')` there is no val in the getter, basically you want the object to deal with your month property

Comment: ah right no need to get it you can just use val, i ll update

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [Computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/computed-properties/):

```
month: DS.attr('date'),  
beginningOfMonth: Ember.computed("month", function(){
  const rawDate = this.get("month");
  if(rawDate){
   return new Date(rawDate.getFullYear(), rawDate.getMonth(), 1);
  }
})
```

Everytime the property `month` changes, also the `beginningOfMonth` property gets updated.

Comment: Problem is I need attribute `month` to be updated as well, because it goes to server backend.